# Update a field with fieldvalue-1,fieldvalue-2 and so on upon selecting some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an inventory table with `serialNbr`, `BatchNbr` and other columns:

```
SerialNbr |  BatchNbr
------     ------     
501600       29183
501601       29183
501602       29183
501603       29183
501604       28183
```

Now if I select the top 2 rows then the batchNbr column with the unselected rows should be updated to '28183-1'and after if i select the rows with batchnbr='29183-1',the remaining unselected rows should be updated to '29183-2' and so on.

for ex: the resulting table for

```
select top2 * from Inventory table where BatchNbr='29183'
```

should give me the result

```
SerialNbr |  BatchNbr
------     ------     
501600       29183
501601       29183
501602       29183-1
501603       29183-1
501604       28183-1
```

in the same way if i select

```
select top1 * from Inventory table where BatchNbr='29183-1'
```

should give me the result

```
SerialNbr |  BatchNbr
------     ------     
501600       29183
501601       29183
501602       29183-1
501603       29183-2
501604       28183-2
```

The result set is just my way of showing how I want the table to be updated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  I should note that in any database that I'm familiar with `top 2` (note the space) would return 2 rows, not 5.

Comment: since its my 1st question to blog..It doesnt allow me to tag..I use sql2012..And Im just showing how my result should come..

Comment: "SQL" is a query language. And there is no version of the standard that is named "sql2012". I assume you mean "Microsoft SQL Server 2012".

Comment: sorry my bad..it is  "Microsoft SQL Server 2012".

Comment: So do you want an update statement that will change the data in your table or a select statement to return all your data with the numbering as explained?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of you doing this?  It doesn't make any sense as to why you would want this complex logic...

Comment: i need an update statement that changes table data

Comment: @iamdave :Its one my college Assignments.I tried doing it by myself..But I am unable to figure out a solution..so finally landed here.

Comment: A select statement is never going to update data. I think you have misinterpreted the assignment. Reread it and see if you can update the question to more accurately reflect what it is you are supposed to do.

Comment: I wanted to update the unselected  field values in a row..some thing like this..UPDATE table
  SET yourstuff(not sure how to' set batchNbr-1')
WHERE yourclauses
    AND table.ID <> (select TOP 1 ID from table where yourclauses)

Comment: @lat  But, why?  Why do you want to update all but the TOP X number of records?  This all sounds like you have misunderstood the requirements.

Comment:  ID will suffix the base ID number with a numeric value – for example for Box 36589, if we split it from a box of 50 to a box of 10 and a box of 40 the box of 100 will be 36859, the remaining box will be 36859-1.  Should that box be broken into two (2) boxes of 200, one will remain 36859-1 and the other will be 36959-2.This is the requirement from which I understood..Let me know if I am wrong